# Simple Softbody animation

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, collision, soft-body

I want to set up a simple scene so i can mess around with soft bodies, i make a floor, i make a "soft body" monkey that sticks to its position and a cube falling on top of it "rigid body active".

[image]

So my First problem is that the head won't stick to it's location and just falls down, i solved that with "goal", setting the "default strength to 1.0" but im unsure if thats even right?

MY section problem is that the "rigid body" cube (active) just falls through the head creating no impact at all.

Comment: give the cube a collision modifier. Softbodies don't react with rigid bodies.

Comment: Yes, setting the goal strength to full is the correct way to make a soft body generally stay in place.

Comment: Ok so i guess i have to animate the "falling" object? at least i get some results now.

But i noticed when setting "goal" to 1.0 the head sticks in air completle emotionless what is exactly what i'm aim for but then the head also ignores every impact of the cube and every value below 1.0 let the head flaot in air.

Is there a way to keep the head from floating but keep the collision?